# How would you analyze this harmony in Mamma by Tchaikovsky

Tags: harmony

[image: Mamma harmonic analysis]

Context: The piece is in G major.

What's going on, harmonically, in the 2nd and 3rd bars here? I'm confused by the first chord (c#be'b') of the 2nd bar and the 2nd chord of bar 3 (ec#g'b')?

So far I'm thinking: x? iii6 vi iii6 x'? iii64

Comment: I'm curious to hear some thoughts from those who have voted to close under the "transcribing or finding a particular song, including identifying chords, notes, key and time signatures, or similar elements" reason. To my mind this is exactly the sort of question that we *do* cover under "technical analysis of a specific, complete work, or well defined section thereof." It even includes the musical excerpt and the author has shown what they have so far. The close-reason is intended for questions like "Do my transcription for me" and "I have these pitches what weird chord does it make."

Comment: Meanwhile, I'm not at all sure of the final answer, but I suspect it will involve "ignoring" the repeated B as a pedal tone?

Comment: Interesting thought about the pedal point: I had never considered the possibility that they could exist in any voice other than the bass. After looking this up just now, I discovered a whole new concept: the inverted pedal point. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pedal_point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Andy_Bonner mentioned in comments, ignoring the B pedal tones in both measures, bar 2 beat 1 is C# and E and bar 3 beat 2 is the same two notes with an added G. Both of those sound like incomplete viio/iii chords with no leading tone, although at this point it really sounds like he has modulated to B minor. The absence of the leading tone is due to the pedal of the B note in the melody and harmony.

The voice leading doesn’t go in the direction you would expect, which would be C#-B and E-D. The G does resolve downwards to the F# though. Despite that the effect sounds like a dominant to tonic motion.

Answer (score 2):

In the first measure, there is a cadence in B minor, and the subsequent progression makes more sense when considered in that key. It becomes

```
ii7  i6  iv  i6  ii7  i64
```

[image: Notated chord progression w/ RNA]

Comment: This is the better answer.  The piece is already in B minor since measure 10 (last beat measure 9 signals a decisive V7-I cadence with F#7/e, the V7 of B minor).  i - ii7 - i6 - iv progression is quite common, and starting measure 12 beat 2 until m. 15 b. 1 the first voice (e-d-e-f#-g-f#-g-f#-e) is no longer the top note.  Top note (b) is simply a common note functioning as pedal point in the harmonic progression, reminiscent of [Chopin's Raindrop prelude bars 28-31](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pedal_point#/media/File:Chopin_Raindrop_Prelude.png).